# Detect if command has printed to stderr

Tags: linux, bash, gcc

I have this program in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char foo[10];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 20 ; i++) {
        foo[i] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I run this script

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -O3 -o hello hello.c
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -e "\033[1;32mcompilation sucess!\033[0m"
else
    echo -e "\033[1;31mcompilation error!\033[0m"
fi
```

It will output

```
hello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:8:10: warning: iteration 10u invokes undefined behavior     [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
foo[i] = 0;
    ^
hello.c:6:2: note: containing loop
  for(i = 0; i<20 ;i++)
  ^
compilation sucess!
```

That is because gcc didn't considered that an error but still output those warnings on `stderr`.

But I still want to detect that within the bash script.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. If your question is about programming/coding, pls post in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ArunVinoth The question is still on topic here, as it is about using a programming tool and it's interaction with the calling script.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Not really, because an answer to the question asked asked in the title would aslo resolve the OPs question (even it wouldn't be the best answer).

Comment: i still want to know how to detect if command has printed to stderr, that would be much better than the accepted awnser

Comment: I think @DavidPostill's answer is the correct one, but if you want to retain the distinction between warnings and errors, as well as detecting notes, you can add ` 2>err` to the end of the `gcc` command and make your test `if [ $? -eq 0 -a ! -s err ]`.

Comment: because what i could do with gcc was nice it solve in this case
but an other command that i couldn't use an special flag like -Werror it would not work, so it is much better to know how to solve in this case

Comment: @AFH That is the corret answer, and it much better because, if i use -Werror changing gcc default behavior which is not what i want, and also with what you did i could use in any command that i need, thanks very helpful

Comment: post that for me to choose as a correct answer

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yeah you are right i deselect DavidPostill answer as accepted

Comment: im now wating for a better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @DavidPostill's answer is the correct one, but if you want to retain the distinction between warnings and errors, as well as detecting notes, you can add `2>err` to the end of the `gcc` command:

```
gcc -O3 -o hello hello.c
```

Then make your test:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 -a ! -s err ]
```

Comment: well your answer is what i really want and it is very helpful, yeah you are right the way i made my question it seems that i really want to make that detection in that case, but an detection in any case it is much better.

Comment: since that code i created just to ilustrate the problem. it is actually not a real code that do 'really usefull stuff'

Answer (score 4):

#### `gcc` didn't consider that as an error

You can use the `-Werror` switch.

> `-Werror` Make all warnings into errors.

Source [Warning Options - Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: although it is just a trick that i could use with this gcc command, but what i really want is something that would help me with any command.

Comment: @gabriel80546 Then you have asked that in your question. But you shouldn't change your question now as it would invalidate existing answers.

Comment: i thought the title was clear